# How to execute the shell-script in NodeJS and wait for it to display and get in the stream?

Tags: node.js, shell

I have connection in hardware with console
But it work's with commands:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IisOA.png)

I create omron.sh because I need to run it in a nodeJS

```
#!/bin/sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/splincode/Develop/omron/c++_modules/libomron/omron-build/lib/
~/Develop/omron/usr/local/bin/omron_790IT_test
```

But me need it's work in NodeJS and write to stream stdout, however, not work

server.js:

```
let http = require('http'), 
    fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url'),
    path = require('path');

let server = new http.Server(); // EventEmitter

server.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1');
server.on("connection", () => console.log("connection"));
server.on('request', (request, response) => {

    console.log('.', request.url)

    let userUrl = decodeURIComponent(url.parse(request.url).pathname);
    let loadFile = false;

    switch(userUrl) {
        case '/': 
            userUrl += 'index.html';
            loadFile = true;
        break;

        case '/omron':

            console.log('omron')

            var util=require('util')
            var exec=require('child_process').spawn('sh', ['omron.sh']);

            // not work
            exec.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
              console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
              response.end(`${data}`);
            }); 

        break;

        default: 
            loadFile = true;
        break;
    };


    if (userUrl === '/') userUrl += 'index.html';


    if (loadFile) {
        let pathname = path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, userUrl));
        fs.readFile(pathname, (err, content) => {
            let mime = require('mime').lookup(pathname);
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', `${mime}; charset=utf-8`);
            response.end(content);
        });
    }


});
```

However, not work it, I need to give the shell-script a response to the output stream, but how?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S82Wl.png)

Comment: u can try node-cmd module

Comment: perfect, very thank's!!!

Comment: can i post my comment as a answer for accepting ?

Comment: yes, of course, you help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> node-cmd

```
 Simple commandline/terminal interface to allow you to run cli or
     bash style commands as if you were in the terminal.
```

*Run commands asynchronously, and if needed can get the output as a string.*

> **so do some thing like this to solve your problem**

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');

cmd.get(
    'pwd',
    function(data){
        console.log('the current working dir is : ',data)
    }
);

cmd.run('whoami');
```